# amiga minix , minix st , macminix and other minix1.5 versions posix compatibility

Tags: posix, minix, amiga

I know minix 2.0 and later have posix compatibility. I want test unix-like operating systems on historicial computers like Commodore Amiga, Atari ST and i386 cpu and run posix compatible apps like pkgsrc, x window system and blackbox wm (for 40Mhz higher versions) minix 1.5 is best os for those systems (better than netbsd) but it is not posix-compatible.

How can I port posix to non-posix *nix operating systems ?

Tnx

Comment: In terms of unix-like system which is still fresh and (almost) POSIX compliant for Amiga - I'd say - try [NetBSD](http://wiki.netbsd.org/ports/amiga/).

Answer (score 0):

You may add an extra POSIX layer, see [ixemul](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX#Compliant_via_compatibility_feature) of AmigaOS.